# Stuck setting up Excel Solver minimization problem

Tags: excel, optimization, solver, minimize

I am new to Excel's solver tool and have a function I would like to minimize.  I am struggling with how to set it up.

The problem is:  I am hosting several events (5) that need social distancing so I am spreading out the people that will come to them.  I have employees that will come to 1, 2, 3, 4, or all 5 events.  It doesn't matter which ones they come to, but I would like to minimize the number that come across all events.  So to make it simple say I have events scheduled Monday to Friday, I would like to make sure that the staff coming to only one event and attend on Monday, don't overlap with the people attending only 2 events - so I can minimize the number each day.

I started off with a total number of staff - say 100 for ease.

Then I have variables as the number of people in each of the "events buckets" I mentioned above (1 through 5). I want to minimize the function of 1*(# of staff for 1 event) + 2*(# of staff for 2 events) + ... + 5*(# staff for 5 events).

I am getting stuck with how to put this into the solver.  I also wrote out the events as well (Event 1, Event 2, etc.) and am still stuck.  Does anyone have a good idea on how to approach this please? to help me set it up.

TIA!

Comment: Sounds like worker scheduling, one book is Practical Management Science by Winston and Albright.

Comment: Thank you! I will check that out.  For now I have just multiplied the number of days by the number of people I have for that day total and divided by 5 events.  It's a start but not totally what I am looking for.  It will at least tell me the number of people I will have for each event when evenly distributed.